# How to retrieve json data from a post request in Pyramid?

Tags: request, pyramid

In **Pyramid**:

```
class ProjectorViews(Layouts):

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

@view_config(renderer="json", name="updates.json", request_method="POST")
def updates_view(self):
    print self.request.params
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {

    function get_updates () {
        data = JSON.stringify({'a':1});
        $.post('/updates.json', data, function(res) {
            });
        }, 'json').done(function() {

        });
    }

    get_updates();
});
```

The console shows `self.request.params` returns `NestedMultiDict([('{"a":1}', u'')])`

How do I get the keys and values in the **NestedMultiDict** object?

If I do `self.request.params.getall("a")`, it reports

```
KeyError: "Key not found: 'a'"
```

And if I do `self.request.json_body`, it reports

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.post()` always sends data with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. Use `$.ajax()` to send the data with correct content type:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(...);
```

On the Pyramid side `request.json_body` is the correct way to access... well, JSON body of the request.